# Rails How to use multiple variable on same class in one view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to use multiple instance of the same class in a view with rails.
Basically i need to show a Branch with all its attributes and in the same page i have a form_for that need an empty Branch object. The problem is that when i create the empty Branch  instance in the controller "@newBranch" the view can't access the first one anymore

here what I do in the controller:

```
def show
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  @branches = @customer.branches
  @newBranch = @customer.branches.new          #this is for the form_for
  @newContact = @newBranch.build_contact       #this is for the fields_for    
end
```

if i try to use a singular item of the collection @branches for example:

```
<div class = "branch_container">
  <%= render :partial => "customers/branch", :collection => @branches %>
</div>
```

and then inside the branch partial:

```
<%= branch.contact.name %>
```

i have the message:

> "undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass"

All the models associations work fine and if i don't instantiate @newBranch and @newContact the problem disappear.

Basically i need to use two instance of the same Class (for example "@branches" in one partial and "@newBranch" in another one) in the same view.

What could be the solution?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end i created @newBranch and @newContact in the view inside the form in the following way:

```
<%= form_for(newBranch = Building.new, :html => { :multipart => true }) do |building_form| %>
    <% newBranch.build_contact %>
    etc... etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

Provide those instances as local vars:

```
 <%= render :partial => "customers/branch", :collection => @branches, :locals => {:branch => @branch, :customer => @customer} %>
```

Oops didn't read well. For a new branch, contact is not set, so nil. Just check for this situation.

```
<% if branch.contact %>
_Your code_
<% else %>
No contact assigned
<% end %>
```

Comment: although it doesn't work, i need to use both variables "@branches" and "@newBranch" in two different partials in the same view, there isn a way to do so???

Comment: You mix two questions: one is the given error, that is caused by an unitialized contact. The other is how to use those instances. Transport them to the partials with the :locals hash. You can give one or both locals to either partial.